# Sorting an array of sub-documents in MongoDB (without using Aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm tryng to sort in Mongo using a field belonging to an array of object. The problem is that i cannot use aggregation and the schema cannot be modified because of external constraints.

this is an example of my documents

```
[{
  "name": "product 1",
  "tags": [{
    "tag": "category",
    "value": "shoes"
  },{
    "tag": "gender",
    "value": "man"
  }]
},
{
  "name": "product 2",
  "tags": [{
    "tag": "category",
    "value": "bags"
  },{
    "tag": "season",
    "value": "fall-winter"
  }]
},
{
  "name": "product 3",
  "tags": [{
    "tag": "category",
    "value": "clothing"
  },{
    "tag": "gender",
    "value": "woman"
  }]
}]
```

let's assume i want to sort them ascending using the tag category
so i should have the documents sorted in that way: "product 2", "product 3", "product 1"

There is a way to do it without aggregation and without modifing the schema?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in `find` query. If `aggregation` is not in the picture then you have to sort this programmatically I guess.

Comment: @Oxenarf : `The problem is that i cannot use aggregation and the schema cannot be modified because of external constraints` --> what do you mean by that ?

Comment: That this can be easly done with aggregation, but i cannot use it because of code constraints (codebase is not owned by me). I should do just a drop-in code modification

Answer (score 1):

> ... i cannot use aggregation...

The following code will do the sorting, if the "category" sub-document is the *first* element of the `tags` array.

```
db.product_cats.find().toArray().sort( (a, b) => {
    return a.tags[0].value > b.tags[0].value;
});
```

If the "category" sub-document appears at *any index* of the array, the following will do the sorting.

```
db.product_cats.find().toArray().sort( (a, b) => {
    let ixa = a.tags.findIndex(e => e.tag == "category");
    let ixb = b.tags.findIndex(e => e.tag == "category"); 
    return a.tags[ixa].value > b.tags[ixb].value;
});
```

If the "category" sub-document is *missing for some* documents then this will do the sorting:

```
db.product_cats.find().toArray().sort( (a, b) => {

    let ixa = a.tags.findIndex(e => e.tag == "category");
    let ixb = b.tags.findIndex(e => e.tag == "category");

    if ( ixa == -1 ) { a.tags = [ ]; a.tags[ ixa] = { value: "" } };
    if ( ixb == -1 ) { b.tags = [ ]; b.tags[ ixa] = { value: "" } };

    return a.tags[ixa].value > b.tags[ixb].value;
});
```

Comment: I assume that this doesn't work with pagination, right?

Comment: I depends (I guess you are referring to the custom sort with pagination: find().sort().skip().limit()). There are some custom solutions; try Googling little bit with _"mongodb pagination with sorting"_.

Answer (score -1):

Your sort criteria should be as following:

`db.sorter.find().sort({"tags.value": 1})`

Outcome

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dd93f4a030a105864baaa"), "name" : "product 2", "tags" : [ { "tag" : "category", "value" : "bags" }, { "tag" : "season", "value" : "fall-winter" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dd93f4a030a105864baab"), "name" : "product 3", "tags" : [ { "tag" : "category", "value" : "clothing" }, { "tag" : "gender", "value" : "woman" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1dd93f4a030a105864baa9"), "name" : "product 1", "tags" : [ { "tag" : "category", "value" : "shoes" }, { "tag" : "gender", "value" : "man" } ] }
```

Comment: This is quite a bit promising but if you wanted to use it - You should trust your application's data/dataset in DB (This query will sort on `value` field of first object found in array `tags`), So as OP has asked to sort on `value` field of objects where `"tag" : "category"` - If for a document in DB, in `tags` array - Object with `"tag" : "category"` is not in the `0th` position of `tags` array then this query would yield incorrect results. So if  `"tag" : "category"` is first object in `tags` for all documents then this query would work :-)